# bitcast integer to vector of char

Tags: clang, llvm, simd, llvm-ir

I just compiled a small piece of C code using clang 3.7:

```
typedef unsigned char char4  __attribute__ ((vector_size (4)));

char4 f1 (char4  v)
{
  return v / 2;
}
```

That functions compile to (I removed debuginfo):

```
define <4 x i8> @f1(<4 x i8> %v) {
entry:
  %div = udiv <4 x i8> %v, bitcast (<1 x i32> <i32 2> to <4 x i8>)
  ret <4 x i8> %div
}
```

According to llvm [documentation](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#bitcast-to-instruction), bitcast operation doesn’t change bits, meaning  to <4 x i8> should yield <2, 0, 0, 0> (or <0, 0, 0, 2>). Am I right?
Therefore, I’ll get Division by Zero exception.

The code I wrote intended to make a broadcast (or splat), and not a bitcast.

Could someone please explain what’s happening?

Thanks!

Comment: apparently it's an inconsistent behavior between clang and gcc. 
The code above runs correctly with gcc, and generates a floating point exception with clang.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually it looks like a bug in clang:

https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=27085

this input code should either not compile, or generate a warning, or compile to a vector splat